# How to use the DelegateCommand on a viewmodel?

Tags: f#

**Is there any example on how to invoke a DelegateCommand on a viewmodel written in F#?**

**I have found the following code for a DelegateCommand implementation [here](http://pastebin.com/kEgWqEnw):**

```
type DelegateCommand<a>(execute : 'a -> unit, ?canExecute : 'a  ->  bool) =
  let event = Event<_,_>()
  interface ICommand with
    member this.CanExecute(param : obj) =
      if canExecute.IsSome then
        canExecute.Value(param :> 'a)
      else true
    member this.Execute (param : obj) =
      execute(param :> 'a)
```

However, being new to F#, I'm not sure if I should use this implementation or if there is some other approach I should be leveraging.

**Here's a test that I would like to execute once I figure out how to execute a DelegateCommand:**

```
module CreateProfileViewModel.Tests

open FsUnit
open NUnit.Framework
open CreateProfile.UILogic

[<Test>]
let ``create profile`` () =

    // Setup
    let viewModel = ViewModel()
    viewModel.FirstName <- "Scott"
    viewModel.LastName <- "Nimrod"

    // Test
    viewModel.Submit.Execute();

    // Verify
    let expected = false // TODO - implement some state-change
    expected |> should equal true
```

**My viewmodel is the following:**

```
module CreateProfile

open Core.UILogic

type ViewModel() =
    inherit ViewModelBase()
    let mutable firstName = ""
    let mutable lastName = ""

    member this.FirstName
        with get() = firstName 
        and set(value) =
            firstName <- value
            base.NotifyPropertyChanged(<@ this.FirstName @>)

    member this.LastName
        with get() = lastName 
        and set(value) =
            lastName <- value
            base.NotifyPropertyChanged(<@ this.LastName @>)
```

**I have the following base-viewmodel:**

```
module Core.UILogic

open System.ComponentModel
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns

type ViewModelBase () =
    let propertyChanged = 
        Event<PropertyChangedEventHandler,PropertyChangedEventArgs>()

    let getPropertyName = function 
        | PropertyGet(_,pi,_) -> pi.Name
        | _ -> invalidOp "Expecting property getter expression"

    interface INotifyPropertyChanged with
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member this.PropertyChanged = propertyChanged.Publish

    member private this.NotifyPropertyChanged propertyName = 
        propertyChanged.Trigger(this,PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))

    member this.NotifyPropertyChanged quotation = 
        quotation |> getPropertyName |> this.NotifyPropertyChanged
```

**Update:**

**I have modified the RelayCommand defined in the MVVM project template for F# to the following:**

```
module UILogic.Interaction

open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Input
open System.ComponentModel

type DelegateCommand (action:(obj -> unit), canExecute:(obj -> bool)) =
    let event = new DelegateEvent<EventHandler>()
    interface ICommand with
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member this.CanExecuteChanged = event.Publish
        member this.CanExecute arg = canExecute(arg)
        member this.Execute arg = action(arg)
```

**I then updated my viewmodel as follows:**

```
module CreateProfile.UILogic

open UILogic.State
open UILogic.Interaction

type ViewModel() =
    inherit ViewModelBase()

    let mutable _firstName = ""
    let mutable _lastName = ""
    let mutable _submitted = false

    member this.FirstName
        with get() = _firstName 
        and set(value) =
            _firstName <- value
            base.NotifyPropertyChanged(<@ this.FirstName @>)

    member this.LastName
        with get() = _lastName 
        and set(value) =
            _lastName <- value
            base.NotifyPropertyChanged(<@ this.LastName @>)

    member this.IsSubmitted
        with get() = _submitted
        and set(value) = _submitted <- value

    member this.Submit =
        new DelegateCommand ((fun _ -> this.IsSubmitted <- true), (fun _ -> true))
```

**However, I am not sure how to invoke the Execute function on the Submit** (DelegateCommand):

```
module CreateProfileViewModel.Tests

open FsUnit
open NUnit.Framework
open UILogic.State
open CreateProfile.UILogic

[<Test>]
let ``create profile`` () =

    // Setup
    let viewModel = ViewModel()
    viewModel.FirstName <- "Scott"
    viewModel.LastName <- "Nimrod"

    // Test
    ignore viewModel.Submit.Execute(); // How to invoke execute?

    // Verify
    viewModel.IsSubmitted |> should equal true
```

I know this is trivial, but I honestly have no clue how to do this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you use ready-made solutions? - FSharp.ViewModule

Comment: @ Foggy Finder : I really want to understand and command F# in my development practice. Guy Coder provided a great reference. I am currently studying their implementation so that I can tinker with it as I try to absorb this language and its mechanics.

Comment: What's your question? Where are you having problems?

Comment: @ Mark Seemann - I updated the state of my question. I'm now stuck on the trivial task of invoking the Execute function of the command on my test.

Comment: Please be careful about changing the question or adding questions after answers have been given. When in doubt ask a new question and link them together. :)

Comment: Respectfully, my question was how to use the DelegateCommand on the viewmodel. Did the context of my question really change?

Comment: My bad. No this one is fine. It was the question I answered the other day and I should have required you to ask a new question. The part about fixing type errors in my view is really a separate question. Your good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `Submit` implementation to this:

```
member this.Submit =
    DelegateCommand ((fun _ -> this.IsSubmitted <- true), (fun _ -> true)) :> ICommand
```

and call it like this:

```
viewModel.Submit.Execute() |> ignore
```

The important change is that the `Submit` method's return type is now `ICommand` instead of `DelegateCommand`. This is due to the use of the upcast operator `:>`.

In F#, all interfaces are **explicitly implemented**. This means that although `DelegateCommand` implements `ICommand`, the methods of `ICommand` aren't visible on objects declared (or inferred) as `DelegateCommand`. When the value is declared (or inferred) to be of the type `ICommand`, on the other hand, only the members of `ICommand` are available.

Answer (score 2):

Since I have not used MVC or MVVM with F# I cannot give a specific code example.

For

> However, being new to F#, I'm not sure if I should use this
>   implementation or if there is some other approach I should be
>   leveraging.

If you use Visual Studio, which also has a [community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) that can be download for free, there are templates for MVC and MVVM.

To access the templates from VS using the menu.

File -> New -> Project

[image]

Expand Online
Expand Templates
Expand Visual F#

[image]

In the upper right for "Search Online Templates" enter a term such as MVC or MVVM

[image]

Pick one or examine a few.

Note: Some of the **templates** are a few years old and F# and Windows has progressed much along the way so I would tend to avoid the older ones. Also the authors of the popular ones can typically be found online and even some are here so ask questions about specifics.

You can also view other templates, controls and **extensions** to VS at the [Visual Studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/) using an Internet browser.

Caution: Some of the **extensions** will cause problems when installed, especially the older or less popular ones, so be careful and don't install them on a production machine until you test them on a different machine first.

Comment: Thanks Guy Coder. Your contribution / guidance partially answered my question. I have updated the state of my question on how to invoke a function that just doesn't appear to be exposed.